Google pubsub SubscriberClient AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'add_done_callback'
I'm working on a project and must consume some messages from my GCP Pubsub subscription. Locally I can consume messages normally.
But when I release the changes to a container in the cloud (something like staging env) I get this error:
2024-05-14 15:50:15,379  ERROR [google.api_core.bidi:_thread_main:678] [pid=1] [tname=Thread-ConsumeBidirectionalStream] [cluster=mt2] [1.65.1] Thread-ConsumeBidirectionalStream caught unexpected exception 'generator' object has no attribute 'add_done_callback' and will exit.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py", line 644, in _thread_main
    self._bidi_rpc.open()
  File "/opt/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/api_core/bidi.py", line 294, in open
    call._wrapped.add_done_callback(self._on_call_done)
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'add_done_callback'

My code is simple: a docker container with a bash entry point starting a python file that init the consumer.
init.py
def main():
    """
    Entrypoint for all consumers
    """

    args = get_args()
    config_settings = get_config_section(args.config_filename)
    consumer = BaseGooglePubSubConsumer(config_settings)
    consumer.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


consumer.py
from functools import cached_property

from google.cloud.pubsub_v1 import SubscriberClient

class BaseGooglePubSubConsumer(BaseConsumer):

    @cached_property
    def consumer(self) -> SubscriberClient:
        json_account_info = self._get_service_account_info()
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json_account_info)
        return SubscriberClient(credentials=credentials)

    def run(self):
        """
        Consumes messages from a Pub/Sub Subscriber.
        """
        streaming_pull_future = self.consumer.subscribe(self._get_subscription_path(), callback=self.process_message)
        with self.consumer:
            try:
                streaming_pull_future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                le.errors = "Failed to process message"
                logger.error(le, exc_info=exc)
                streaming_pull_future.cancel()
                streaming_pull_future.result()
            finally:
                le.end()
    def process_message(self, message: Message) -> None:
        # message.ack()
        logger.info(message)

I have read about the error and I found a similar issue without an answer: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/issues/1180

I have the same issue. It works locally both in Macbook M2 and Windows WSL. But once it is containerized in docker, it throws the exactly the same error.
